# Well-known packages are not shown in synaptic package manager

Tags: 12.04, repository

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, both on My laptop and Desktop PC.

I've run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

on both of the platforms. In my PC I can install these packages by searching in "Synaptic Package Manager":

```
build-essential

cmake

ant

jdk7
```

.....

but in My laptop I cannot find theses packages in "Synaptic Package Manager". I've installed both of the operating systems from the same .iso file.

Why in my laptop I can't find most of the packages that I find in My PC ? is there something wrong with my repositories ?

Comment: Several reason could cause it, and it's hard to tell, unless you provide more info. Have you compared my `/etc/apt/sources.list` files on "My PC" and "My laptop"?

Comment: server names for these two system differs, because I chose best server for repository. Does it make any difference ? The number of lines on both files are equal but the server name and domain differes

Comment: Yes, it does, as, in that case, the two machines use different repositories.

Comment: Okay let me check and see what happens if I change both of them to Mainserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the Synaptics package manager:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove synaptic && sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Then update the system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the typo, I fixed it. I mean when you type jdk7 in search filter it brings openjdk-7-jdk so there's no need to type the whole term.

Comment: Can you install them with command line or Software Center in both PC s?

Comment: Yes I can install all of them from the command line, But I don't wanna do this, Since I want to know why this is happening !

Comment: Why this has happened? is this because I installed synaptic first and then used sudo apt-get update ?

Comment: Certain corruptions are happening during the installation. (Even in other OS)